# UTL_SMTP insufficient privilege

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to send mail using oracle utl_smtp and have the below error :

environment :

- Oracle cloud
- os : linux
- DB : "Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
  Version 18.4.0.0.0"
- I am login to the database with ADMIN User.

How to give privilege to ADMIN user?
Any help?
Thanks

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 265
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 319
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 363
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.SEND_MAIL_SMTP", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 2
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

Comment: Does ADMIN user have EXECUTE rights on the package?

Comment: Are you using the Autonomous Database or is this a DB System?

Answer (score 0):

`ADMIN` user looks like user you (or your DBA) created for certain purposes. It seems that it lacks privileges on some objects; `UTL_SMTP` being one of them.

If you are allowed to connect as a privileged user (such as SYS, if there's no other), do that and

```
grant execute on utl_smtp to admin;
```

Otherwise, ask your DBA to do that.